# How to set allowPrivilegeEscalation with Quarkus Kubernetes Extension

Tags: java, kubernetes, quarkus, quarkus-extension

The Quarkus Kubernetes Extension allows to set Kubernetes Security Context information like this:

```
quarkus.kubernetes.security-context.run-as-user=1000
quarkus.kubernetes.security-context.run-as-group=3000
quarkus.kubernetes.security-context.fs-group=2000
quarkus.kubernetes.security-context.run-as-non-root=true
```

However, if I want to set `allowPrivilegeEscalation` as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) there is no option anywhere and I also cannot overwrite or extend my deployment.yaml file.

I tried to search the documentation and did not find the parameter among the security-context or other parameters for the Quarkus Kubernetes Extension. I also usually use the Quarkus Helm Extension and am not very in depth with the Kubernetes Extension.

How can I set the allowPrivilegeEscalation-variable? Is it necessary to hack around with Decorate?